# Get ID of currently open camera

Tags: android, camera

How can I get the ID of the currently open android camera from an android camera instance? I can't see it in the parameters and getCameraInfo requires the id as a parameter.

Comment: If by "currently open android camera", you mean one that you opened with `Camera.open()`, you need to hold onto that `int` value yourself.

Comment: @CommonsWare okay, so there's definitely no way to tell from the camera instance? Seems a bit strange

Comment: I can't quibble with the "strange" adjective. :-)

Comment: Ok, but what if I opened the camera with Camera.open() without a specific cameraId because I need the main back-facing camera? Is it always CameraId = 0?

Comment: This is really strange, you can get CameraInfo with its number, but not from a camera object. And you can't get camera number from camera. Weird.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There isn't a way to get the id of the currently open android camera. I ended up storing the id when I opened it.

Comment: Your way is best idea. Really surprised when Google company still not support this checker : currently is Back camera or Front camera. Thank you. Store in single ton way is best way.

Comment: And which method of the Camera do yout use to find the id?

Comment: @androidevil There's no method to find the id, I stored whichever integer 'id' I chose when I called `Camera.open(id)`

Answer (score 23):

It is just a number of the camera, so you loop through looking for the camera you want.

Here is a snippet to find the front-facing camera:

```
int cameraId = -1;
int numberOfCameras = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCameras; i++) {
  CameraInfo info = new CameraInfo();
  Camera.getCameraInfo(i, info);
  if (info.facing == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
    Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Camera found");
    cameraId = i;
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: This gets the ID of the front camera, I need the ID of the camera that is currently being used! Sorry for confusion.

Comment: @mbdavis - I don't think you can get that, but if you loop through as above and try to open each camera, the one you can't open is in use, but remember to release them immediately after opening. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html

Comment: Not only does this not get info about the _open_ camera, it gets the _index_ of the camera (in some list); not the ID. Maybe index is often same as ID, but I know they are not _always_ the same.

Answer (score 2):

```
  private int findFrontFacingCameraID() {
        int cameraId = -1;
        // Search for the front facing camera
        int numberOfCameras = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCameras; i++) {
          CameraInfo info = new CameraInfo();
          Camera.getCameraInfo(i, info);
          if (info.facing == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Camera found");
            cameraId = i;
            break;
          }
        }
        return cameraId;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

For Kotlin with newer camera API:

```
fun getCameraId(context: Context, facing: Int): String {
    val manager = context.getSystemService(CAMERA_SERVICE) as CameraManager

    return manager.cameraIdList.first {
        manager
            .getCameraCharacteristics(it)
            .get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING) == facing
    }
}
```

Valid values for `facing` are:

```
CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_FRONT
CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_BACK
CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_EXTERNAL
```